# Validate input value against blacklist array

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm currently using [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/), I have a form with four input fields - Word, Country, Age & Sex.

Country, Age & Sex validate without any problems, but Word doesn't want to validate - I'm trying to get the Word value to check its self against a blacklist before validating, I'm trying to prevent users submitting offensive words.

At the moment, whatever word I type into the Word input field, it always shows as an error and doesn't want to validate.

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong, I'd appreciate the help!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DznoX.png)

JS

```
 /* Blacklist Array */
    var blacklist = ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz', /* many more banned words... */ ];

    /* Blacklist Validation */
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("word", function(value) {
      var in_array = $.inArray(value, blacklist);
      if (in_array == -1) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });

    /* Submit Validation */
    $("#submit").validate({
      errorPlacement: function(error, element){},
      rules: {
        word: {
          required: true
        },
        country: {
          required: true
        },
        age: {
          required: true
        },
        sex: {
          required: true
        }
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert('Submitted');
      }
    });
```

HTML

```
  <form methord="post" name="wordsubmit" id="submit">
    <div class="inner">
      <input class="word" name="word" placeholder="Your Word" type="text"/>
      <select class="country" name="country" size='1'>
        <option value="">Your country</option>
      </select>
      <select class="age" name="age" size='1'>
        <option value="">Age</option>
        <option value="18-24">18-24</option>
        <option value="25-34">25-34</option>
        <option value="35+">35+</option>
      </select>
      <select class="sex" name="sex" size='1'>
        <option value="">Sex</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option vlaue="Female">Female</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: so exactly you want the works you have added in error must be validated at the time of input in textbox.Isn't So?

Comment: why are you `toUpperCase()` on the `value`? None of the words in `blacklist` are upper case?

Comment: Yes, So if the user types an offensive word the field would become invalid and if the user types a none offensive word the field would become valid and ready for submit.

Comment: @Jamiec the input value is uppercase, so I converted the array to uppercase so the values could match?

Comment: @Adam - you werent though - you were setting the user entered value to upper case, even though the blacklist was all lowercase. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in the `word` method you add is backwards; if the word entered is not found in the array (ie. `$.inArray` returns `-1`) then you want to return `true` as this word is valid.

That being the case, you can simplify the logic to just this:

```
/* Blacklist Validation */
jQuery.validator.addMethod("word", function(value) {
    return $.inArray(value, blacklist) == -1;
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/1tnzn2vt/)

Note in the example I have removed the error message suppression so you can see the code working.

It would also be worth making sure that the case is consistent for values in the blacklist array, so you can then cast the entered word to the same case using `value.toUpperCase()` or `value.toLowerCase()`, as currently `FoO` won't match `foo` and will be marked as valid.

Comment: Thank you for yourself @Rory!

Comment: This is not working for me. I have no errors. I don't understand why is not working.

Comment: @Ionut it would be best for you to start a new question, including the code relevant to your own situation

Comment: We also need to see how you have setup the jQuery validation plugin, make sure the field names match etc. There could be a lot of reasons why something doesn't work for you specifically

Comment: I validate correctly, because the required validations works, only this custom validation not working. I put the name from the validation on the addMethod function. No validation error is triggered when I enter a string from the fiddle array.

Comment: I runned the addMethod code in the console and it returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

- You use `toUpperCase()` (in your original question) for comparing with a list that has only lower case words. I suppose you intended to use `toLowerCase()`;
- You return `false`/`true` in the opposite sense. You'll want to return `true` when the word is not found in the blacklist (returned value -1)
- You check the whole input against the black list, so as soon as the input contains more than one word, the validation will never find it in the blacklist, even though one of the input words may be black listed.

I would suggest to turn your black list into a regular expression. That will make your code quite concise:

```
var blacklist = /\b(foo|bar|fizz|buzz)\b/; /* many more banned words... */

jQuery.validator.addMethod("word", function(value) {
    return !blacklist.test(value.toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`addMethod`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) says of the function passed in:

> The actual method implementation, returning true if an element is valid.

JQuery's `inArray` method returns `-1` is the element is **NOT** found, and the index of the item if it is.

Looking at your method it returns `true` if the element **IS** found in your blacklist - so its basically the wrong way round.

---

Also, as I commented you were doing a `toUpperCase` on the entered `value` (which you've subsequently removed) - however if you want your blacklist check to be case insensitive you probably need to convert the user entered value to whatever casing your blacklist has - so either have your blacklist entirely lowercase and use `toLowerCase()` on the value, or have the blacklist all upper case and have `toUpperCase()` on the value.

---

This code should work

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("word", function(value) {
  var in_array = $.inArray(value.toLowerCase(), blacklist);
  return in_array == -1;
});
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, yes I did.